# How to bring and display minted NFT image (ERC-721) in polygon Mumbai testnet. Attached the screenshot

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, nft, polygon

[image]

In polygon testnet we are trying to bring minted NFT image in the image section, is there are any possibility to bring them, please let us know how to do that.